# Which 1seg TV tuner is supported? (mobile ISDB-T)

Tags: tv-tuner

The [[image]1seg](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/1seg) protocol allows Japanese and Brazilian cellphones to show television.

There are many USB-stick 1seg tuners for sale, to watch TV on PC. Is any of them usable with Ubuntu?

Comment: also known as ワンセグ

Answer (score 3):

1seg is better known as `ISDB-T` for cellphones, laptops, etc.
Therefore, google for `ISDB-T USB dongle Ubuntu` in order to find available products.

You need to load the smsusb and smusbtv kernel modules (if they do not load automatically) and then use a program to scan for the available channels.

Look at http://www.dealextreme.com/ for available products.

Comment: With all my good will, I went through pages and pages of Google results for ISDB-T USB dongle Ubuntu and similar queries, but not a single result answers my question. Thanks for mentioning ISDB-T, though.

Comment: Did you find a Linux-compatible dongle on the DX website? There are several, read the customer reviews to find a compatible one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I browsed all comments of all ISDB-T devices, and unfortunately none is said to be working with Linux...